# Fix MonoTouch install?

Tags: xamarin.ios

My MonoTouch install is screwed somehow (MonoDevelop won't even open).
So yesterday I deleted /Developer/MonoTouch off my Mac because that was the only directions I could find for uninstalling it.  Today I tried reinstalling both it and MonoDevelop.  Both installers ran fine, but I still have the same issue so I went to "uninstall" it again...and that directory doesn't exist this time.
Then I went to install an older version (2.6.7) and that installer tells me that I have a newer version already installed.
So....what do I do?

I am in a very, very bad mood because of all this right now.  A months worth of work is now pointless unless I can get this running again.

**EDIT**

I finally got an older version of MonoTouch to install.  Version 2.6.7 that was downloaded off of their site.  Now when I run MonoDevelop I get an error that says "MonoDevelop requires the Mono Framework version 2.6.7 or later" and gives me the option to "Cancel" or "Download".

This is the error that I got that started this whole thing.  I installed 2.6.7 but it doesn't recognize, and if I install 2.8 it just won't launch (icon bounces 3 times then does nothing, no error, no app).

**EDIT 2**

The other thing of note is that no matter how many times I install/uninstall/reinstall any version of the Mono Framework, nothing at all shows up in /Developer/MonoTouch.

I don't know how important that is, but considering something used to be there until this problem started I thought it worth mentioning.

Also since this problem started, I can no longer open any .xib files inside of Interface Builder.  Whether that means one created in XCode or opening Interface Builder then creating a new View.  Interface Builder runs fine, but as soon as I try to open any .xib it crashes with [this](http://pastebin.com/n7zkKau5) error report.

I notice it says something about libxml2 in there which WAS installed yesterday and is probably the root cause of this...but I have uninstalled and reinstalled that as well with no luck.

Comment: try `locate MonoTouch` in Terminal.

Comment: thank you for that, I just have to create the locate database first...no idea how long that's going to take but thanks.

Comment: Apparently there are quite a few folders and files on my machine with "MonoTouch" in the name...but none of them is anything but my projects

Comment: Its a bit confusing since you seem to be using MonoTouch, Mono and MonoDevelop interchangeably.  Could you please install the latest Mono from: http://mono-project.com/Downloads and the latest MonoDevelop from http://monodevelop.com/Download  If MonoDevelop still fails to launch, open a terminal and type:

/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/MonoDevelop

Comment: I am not using them interchangeably.
MonoTouch 2.6.7 is installed.
MonoDevelop 2.4 is installed.
When MonoDevelop is launched it tells me it needs MonoTouch 2.6.7 or higher to work.
If I install MonoTouch 2.8 and launch MonoDevelop the icon for MonoDevelop bounces 3 times then nothing happens.  No error or message of any kind and no MonoDevelop to work in.

Comment: When I run that command in terminal with MonoTouch 2.6.7 installed I get this output:

`/applications/monodevelop.app/contents/macos/mono-version-check: line 19: mono: command not found
16:186: execution error: No user interaction allowed. (-1713)
Cannot launch MonoDevelop
MonoDevelop requires the Mono Framework version 2.6.7 or later.`

When I run it with MonoTouch 2.8 installed, Terminal pauses for a second...and then nothing...just like if I tried to click on the MonoDevelop icon.

Comment: You are using them interchangeably, since the current MonoTouch version is 3.1.3, the current Mono version is 2.8.1 and the current MonoDevelop version is 2.4

Comment: I see, I am using MonoTouch and Mono interchangeably.
When I go to the mono-project.com/Downloads page it gives me the download for "Mono 2.8"...so if MonoTouch is at version 3.1.3...where do I get that?

Comment: To answer your latest question, you would redownload MonoTouch from the link provided when you purchased your license.  If you have lost that link you can email monotouch@novell.com with your license information and they can re-provide it.

Comment: I do not have a license, I am evaluating the product (and so far...that evaluation is not going well in my opinion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Mono 2.6.7 or later, please download and install:

http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/archive/2.8/macos-10-x86/10/MonoFramework-2.8_10.macos10.novell.x86.dmg

Comment: Per the comments above, when I do that, MonoDevelop doesn't launch.  The app icon bounces 3 times then nothing happens.  Same if I try to launch it from Terminal per your instructions above.

Comment: Then your mono install is corrupted, what does "ls -al /usr/bin/mono" say in a terminal?  What does "ls -al /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions" say?  What does "ls -al /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono" say?  What does "mono -V" say?

Comment: First: lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  48 Aug  5  2009 /usr/bin/mono -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono


Second: total 8
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  admin  170 Nov  8 10:12 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 root  admin  306 Nov  8 10:12 ..
drwxrwxrwx   3 root  admin  102 Nov  8 10:12 2.6.7
drwxrwxrwx  13 root  admin  442 Nov  8 10:12 2.8
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    3 Nov  8 10:12 Current -> 2.8


Third: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  4217028 Oct  7 13:52 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono

Comment: Fourth: Mono JIT compiler version 2.8 (tarball Thu Oct  7 12:23:27 MDT 2010)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           normal
 SIGSEGV:       normal
 Notification:  Thread + polling
 Architecture:  x86
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          debugger softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)

Comment: What does: "ls -al /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/" say?  What does "ls -al /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/" say?

Comment: To the first: http://pastebin.com/i0u3ymnS
To the second: http://pastebin.com/dWUKM7UX

Comment: Based on all this and your comments about Interface Builder crashing in libxml2, it seems you've corrupted something fundamental on your system.  Is this also you: http://www.pubbs.net/201011/libxml/11279-xml-libxml2-messed-up-monotouch-and-interface-builder.html

Comment: Yes that is me.  Posted that based on things I discovered working on this with you.
It does seem that this is outside of MonoTouch and Interface Builder so thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Turns out that the issue was related to the libxml2 thing, the OS is reinstalled, but MonoTouch still won't work correctly but I have opened a new issue for that.